# Python - Fastapi nats client timeout issue

Tags: python, fastapi, nats.io

I have a fastapi application running as a microservice which is using the python nats client to publish messages. But every time I do a nats request this way, I'm getting request timeout, but this after 3-4 retries all messages go out at the same time. (There are no synchronous calls throughout the application).

This issue does not arise if I do a request from my nats listener. What could be the issue?

Comment: This question needs a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're asking about.